# Select Data frame between two dates of a date column

Tags: pandas, date, dataframe

I would like to subset a data frame based on a date column, which originally has this format:

```
3/22/13
```

After I transform it to a date:

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m/%d/%y')
```

I get this:

```
2013-03-22 00:00:00
```

Now I would like to subset it with something like this:

```
 df.loc[(df['date']>'2014-06-22')]
```

But that either gives me an empty data frame or full data frame, that is no filtering.

Any suggestions how I can get this to work?

remark: I am well aware that similar questions have been asked in other forums but I could not figure out a solution since my date column looks different.

Comment: Your code should working, can you test `between` like `df.loc[df['date'].between('2013-03-22', '2013-06-22')]` ?

Comment: jesrael, your code also gave me the same problem, i.e. an empty dataset. @Scott: Yeah, the dataset goes from 2013 to 2018

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you have to convert your starting date and final date into a datetime format. Then you can apply multiple conditions inside df.loc. Do not forget to reassign your modifications to your df :

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m/%d/%y')

date1 = datetime.strptime('2013-03-23', '%Y-%m-%d')
date2 = datetime.strptime('2013-03-25', '%Y-%m-%d')

df = df.loc[(df['date']>date1) & (df['date']<date2)]
```